# Read .xls row cell by cell

Tags: java, xml, excel, jxl

I'm writing a Java app to create an .xml file in which some attributes' values come from an .xls file. I'm using jxl libraries to read the .xls file but it reads column by column, while I need to read one row cell by cell and put cell values into .xml attributes.

How to read row cell by cell from .xls?

```
FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(minmaxoh);

    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);

    try{
        wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(workbook);
        Sheet sheet0=wb.getSheet(0);

        for(int i=0;i<sheet0.getColumns(); i++){
            for(int j=0;j<sheet0.getRows();j++){
                    Cell cell1=sheet0.getCell(i,j);

                    //String cell=(String)cell1;
    CellType digits=cell1.getType();

    if(digits==CellType.NUMBER ){

        System.out.println(" "+cell1.getContents());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try interchanging the for loops for rows and columns

```
for(int i=0;i<sheet0.getColumns(); i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sheet0.getRows();j++){
```

to

```
 for(int i=0;i<sheet0.getRows();i++){
       for(int j=0;j<sheet0.getColumns(); j++){
```